# How to plot markers on a python graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph

I have a huge python data frame that looks like this.

```
 HR     ICULOS  SepsisLabel PatientID
100.3      1         0          1
117.0      2         0          1
103.9      3         0          1
104.7      4         0          1
102.0      5         0          1
88.1       6         0          1
```

Access the whole file [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am1j7gBl276r-Swj0EYA4tWSR_FH?e=EdHzxf). I Plotted the HR Column based on ICULOS like [this](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am1j7gBl276r-S2a-Y3BHala2mFH?e=E77NQS). The code is here:

```
ax = plt.gca()

ax.set_title("Patient ID = 1")
ax.set_xlabel('ICULOS')
ax.set_ylabel('HR Readings')
dummy.plot(kind='line',x='ICULOS',y='HR',ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

What I want is to add a marker on the HR graph based on SepsisLabel (See the file). At ICULOS = 249, Sepsis Label changes from 0 to 1. I want to show that at this point on graph, sepsis label changed ([This is what I want](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am1j7gBl276r-S6NozYGDUSmYJtf?e=v2TgFm)).

Comment: If you know to which point you want to add a marker, you can just use plt.scatter() to do so.

Comment: I don't want scatter plot. I want this line plot so I can easily see the trend. Also, The dataset is huge. I want code to figure out at what ICULOS, sepsisLabel changes from 0 to 1. Here I mentioned just for ease

Comment: I did not mean a whole scatter plot. You can create a scatter plot on top of the one you already have and use a limited amount of points. This means you need to find the indexes where sepsisLabel changes from 0 to 1, and only pass those points to the scatter plot. As far as i know there is no built in functions to check when it changes though, you will need to write code that does that yourself.

Comment: As far as getting the exact indexes where sepsisLabel changes to 1, you could use np.ediff1d()

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, what do you want to do is to 1) find an index of value change and 2) plot (scatter) there point with a specific marker type.

Regarding 1), you can use `dummy['SepsisLabel'].diff().idxmax()`. `diff()` creates array of 0s with 1s at every change from 0 to 1 and back. `idxmax()` then finds first change - the point you are looking for.

Ad 2): You can just use `plt.scatter(x, y, marker='X')` before `plt.show()` to draw a point. Anything you draw (`pandas`, `matplotlib` or others) before calling `plt.show()` will still appear in the plot.